# javascript library to parse string to xml that have multiple root node?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xhtml

i have ajax that will return response text below :

```
<div id="root_1">
    <div id="insideRoot1"> value inside root 1 </div id="insideRoot1">
</div id="root_1">

<div id="root_2">
    <div id="insideRoot2"> value inside root 2 </div id="insideRoot2">
</div id="root_2">

<div id="root_3">
    <div id="insideRoot3"> value inside root 3 </div id="insideRoot3">
</div id="root_3">
```

as far as i know valid xml must have 1 root node,

using DOMparser to parse that string to xml not working.

is there any javascript library to parse string that have multiple root node to xml. then read the node of it with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Just surround the string with a dummy start & end tag to create a single root node.

You can then parse it as normal XML and read the children.

Comment: later every node from ajax responseText will take place in separate dom. so base your answer. i must create another new dom element in my html document. then place ajax responseText in innerHTML of that new element. then select the node of it and place it with my desire. then delete that new element that not useful anymore. there is another way? i think its little complicated for me

Comment: @ilike: You don't need to put the dummy node in the document.

Comment: how? i fail using DOMparser to handle it